# CLR Application not starting

Tags: c#, c++, dll, clr

I have spent now some days trying to resolve this one. My problem is that my developed Application won't start on other systems. There is no error message, nothing.

To be more specific, i have developed an application accessing native C/C++ librarys provided by a manufactorer. Therefore in my solution i have my WPF Application and a CLR Dynamic Link Library Project working with the native code. So when running the application on my Computer where visual studio is installed i can run the application without any problems, but it won't start on other computers without visual studio installed. I figured out, its the "Desktopdevelopment with c++" package, that must be installed. Can i determine what needs to be installed so that other people can use this application without installing the whole visual studio community IDE? Or even better, is it maybe possible to embedd all resources into my exe file, that nothing else needs to be installed?

I'm thankfull for every tip ;) cheers patrick

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio Redistributable package on the other machines? It's available here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) also make sure you are building a release configuration and not a debug one since Debug binaries require Visual Studio to be installed.

Comment: `native C/C++ librarys provided by a manufactorer` Those should have come with some documentation spelling out their runtime dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @drescherjm. The Redistributable was already installed but indeed i needed to build the release version. Now it works.

@dxiv The Documentation is very poor on that api. I had lot of other issues and seems like other people too. Recommendation was to not use this library in other threads :D :D

Thank you both for your help!!
Cheers patrick